# Can a noun clause be part of an adverbial phrase?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, clauses, adverbial-phrases

For example:

1. "He was punished **for what he did to his brother**."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can! The sentence you suggest is perfectly correct and idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Parse

He was punished for//what he did to his brother.

The verb *punish* here takes the preposition **for**.

"what he did to his brother" is a  noun clause used as a direct object of punished for.

He was asked about//what he did for his brother.
He denied //what he did to his brother.

Same idea.

I don't think this is anything adverbial per se.